# How to convert "hover effect" to a "click effect" in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I know how this sounds but is it possible to change hover effect for click with jquery?

I have this [site](http://dissbike.pl) and If you look at the menu (e-rowery, especially) you can see that it works on hoover. Unfortunately non of the touch screen devices uses hoover so i would like to convert it to a click menu instead of hoover. Any ideas how to do that with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

actually, there is no problem, since the links that have sub-menus go nowhere (as opposed to them going somewhere, you can't open the submenu with a click). you can easily convert them to clicks.

however, you have to note that you need a substitute for "mouseout". you can do this by adding an event handler to the body. the user can click on any empty space outside the menu to close the submenus. to do this, the handler in the body must check if the element clicked was a link in the menu. if not, close all menus (and if it was a link other than the menu's, go to it).

you can use jQuery's `.on()` method for adding handlers to the parent for the child.

---

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x2uJQ/2/)

```
click anywhere in the body
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">click me, i am inside, i have a submenu</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<a class="outside" href="#">i am outside with no submenu, you can redirect</a>

$('body').on('click', function() {
    alert('body clicked, close menus');
});

$('.menu a').on('click', function() {
    alert('link clicked, open my submenu');
    return false; //prevent further code execution, prevent body's handler
});

$('a.outside').on('click', function() {
    alert('outside link clicked, go to page');
    return false; //prevent further code execution, prevent body's handler
});
```

​

Comment: can you be more deceptive, I am kind of new to jquery:/

Comment: Thank you but still something's wrong because I can click the link but the hover effect is still on and I cant get to the second child in e-rowery.

Comment: if the hover is an effect of jQuery, you can use `.off()` to remove it. if it's a CSS style, remove the style that does it.